# Designing my own private messaging system in Rails 3.1 and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I am trying to design a rails application with Mongoid that has a private messaging system

Is there any tutorials that would help me get started?

How should i begin on creating a rails messaging system for Mongoid?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial about how to create a messaging system. The url is not longer available. But you can give this a try: http://web.archive.org/web/20100823114059/http://www.novawave.net/public/rails_messaging_tutorial.html